# "ssh -L <port>" only working from local machine

Tags: linux, ssh, nat, tunneling

I mean if I've got something like this:

```
ssh -L 9000:itc.ua:80 andy@localhost
```

It will open port `9000` on my local machine and when I hit `http://localhost:9000` in Firefox it will forward to `itc.ua:80`
So far so good.

BUT what if I want to hit that opened port `9000` from a different machine?
For example I've got another machine on my local network and on that other machine I'm trying to navigate with Firefox to `http://<IP ADDRESS OF MACHINE WITH MY SSH -L 9000 Tunnel>:9000` and this fails.

Is there any way to make it work?

Answer (score 7):

Try `ssh -g -L ...`

From `man ssh`:

> **-g**
>
> Allows remote hosts to connect to local forwarded ports. If used on a multiplexed connection, then this option must be specified on the master process.

From `man ssh_config`:

> **GatewayPorts**
>
> Specifies whether remote hosts are allowed to connect to local forwarded ports. By default, ssh(1) binds local port forwardings to the loopback address. This prevents other remote hosts from connecting to forwarded ports. GatewayPorts can be used to specify that ssh should bind local port forwardings to the wildcard address, thus allowing remote hosts to connect to forwarded ports. The argument must be “yes” or “no”. The default is “no”.